# How to get origin property of reverted file in filepond

Tags: filepond

I followed filepond doc about Setting Initial Files to prepopulat filepond. Now, I want to write a custom revert function in which I can use different function based on file origin.

**The following is a hypothetical code to show what I want to achieve:**

```
#hypothetical code         
     revert: (uniqueFileId, load, error) => {
            console.log('uniqueFileId is +' uniqueFileId);

            const origin = ? ; //cannot figure out how to get file origin.

            if (origin =='1'){ // origin is input
                // run default function to remove input file

            } else if (origin =='2'){ // origin is limbo
                // run custom function to remove limbo file from server
                }); 

            } else { // origin is local
                // run custom function to remove local file from server

            }
            error('oh my goodness');

            // Should call the load method when done, no parameters required
            load();
        },
```

**Question 1:**
I cannot get origin of the file. I tried following code inside of revert function, none of them worked. How should I get the origin of the file?

```
    const origin = origin;
    console.log('origin is ' + origin); // console not printing anything, no error message.

    const origin1 = FilePond.getFile().origin;
    console.log('origin1 is ' + origin1);// console not printing anything, no error message.
```

**Question 2:**
suppose i can get origin of the file, how should I write function to remove input file? (in the origin == 1 case)? One thing I found was that when I click cancel button on newly added file, the uniqueFileId was 'success'. I am not sure if this is the way it should be because the file hasn't been uploaded or I have done something wrong.

In the case of 'LIMBO', the uniqueFileId was correctly shown as the file name such as '1.jpg'. I was able to pass this Id to the server.

Answer (score 2):

The `server.revert` function is only called for `limbo` origins and input files that have been processed. For `local` files the `server.remove` function is used. The origin is not available in the server methods.

If you do need it you could store a separate list of files and compare the file id. In the `server.revert` method you can then use that list to see what kind of file it is.

```js
const myFiles = {
   'myuniquefileid': 'limbo',
   'myotheruniquefileid': 'local',
}

FilePond.create({
  server: {
    revert: (uniqueFileId, load, error) => {
      // origin
      const origin = myFiles[uniqueFileId];

      // more code

    }
  }
})
```

Comment: `@Rik` Thanks for pointing out that `revert` is for `limbo` origin! I should have used `local` rather than `limbo`. I was able to consult this github post (https://github.com/pqina/filepond/issues/192) to populate filepond with `local` files.